Limit CPU, memory for a specific user or db in a postgres DB instance
Currently we have multiple DBs hosted in a single postgres instance.
We want to limit the CPU usage for specific db/users with in that DB instance.
Is it possible to do those resource management operations in postgres?

No, that is not possible. Your databases would have to be on different machines or in different containers.

You can limit work_mem, hash_mem_multiplier, and few other settings by user.  Documentation here and here. This does not limit overall memory or CPU but might help in tuning for overall server and user efficiency.
For example, if there is 1 set of production services that run queries that sort more data or run more complicated/parallel queries (like a report writer service), perhaps lowering work_mem/hash_mem_multiplier as the server parameter and increasing for this user might allow more PostgreSQL to function more efficiently in the same memory envelope. Memory, in the form of work_mem, is not "wasted" on users who do not need it. Or for more time sensitive users they get more resources, up to what is needed, and lower time sensitive users might have to use an external sort/hash.
Or maybe memory is not a problem but CPU is so you can adjust settings accordingly.
Some of these can also be changed on a session level. Such as before a query that needs resources set higher and then set back after. But I found that when a user knows that can tweak a "go faster sometimes" setting, then that setting is always used, regardless if that setting might hurt others. Careful here.
Changing these for the user or session takes tuning, monitoring, maintenance, etc. It does not limit CPU or memory given to the user. But it might allow you to solve the problem by giving some users more memory, in the form of work_mem, while reserving memory as a whole. Taken too far, each user has a separate configuration which makes maintenance hard as users tend to change patterns over time and data certainly changes over time.
This mechanism has worked for me, making every query in the server work faster after I benchmarked/adjusted/monitored settings for the "problematic" services.
